# Redirect a.com/a.html to b.com/a.html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect a.com/a.html to b.com/a.html htaccess Apache. I have several subdomains that are not being redirected to the b.com(which is fine). and the example below is only the first domain that needs to be redirected. Three other domains are needed to be redirected to b.com as well with all of their subpages as a.com/a.html to b.com/a.html. Any hints?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?nexus21\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tvlift\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.tvlift.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Why did you tag this with [php]?

Comment: My mistake. Some redirects are done with PHP header location

Answer (score 0):

I would do each subdomain redirect separately. That way it is cleaner and more maintainable. If you are redirecting few known files then name them directly.

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    "^/foo\.html$"  "bar.html"  [R]
```

If there are lots of file or you will be adding in future then use a pattern

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   "^/docs/(.+)"  "http://new.example.com/docs/$1"  [R,L]
```

See this page 
[http://httpd.apache.org](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html)